# MySQL Cluster Auto-Installer

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I am using MySQL Cluster Auto-Installer. I click the next button while keeping the default configurations. But finally when i click Deploy and start cluster it will give me the following error. [image: Error i am getting]

I cant find any information regarding this message in the web.

Comment: So basically this is starting a windows service ('N49') and it is failing.  Probably ndb_mgmd.  I would check the MySQL/Cluster error log for Node 49, and also the windows event log, to figure out why that node failed to start.

Comment: @Trent Lloyd how may i find the  MySQL/Cluster error log for Node 49

Answer (score 0):

@dennypanther, It's always in the config dir such as: /usr/local/mysql/mysql-cluster/ and It´s called "ndb_49_cluster.log".

In addition, maybe you could find it within a folder named with the same node id, for example: /usr/local/mysql/mysql-cluster/49/.

It depends how you configure it in the installation process.

I guess you resolved this problem a long time ago, however I try to help you as much as posible.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug fixed in recent 7.5 release of MySQL Cluster.

Comment: Could you point a link to where you found this could be a bug that has been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I did the bug fix myself, there was an issue with
not handling Windows character set properly that
made the start of the management server fail.
Fixed by handling also Windows character set
in messages from OS. Don't recall exact version
it was fixed in, but definitely fix is in latest
7.5.